# How to I combine a sql server 2005 datetime and an integer field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have 2 fields in a table on sql server 2005.  One is a datetime field where the date is correct and all the times are 12:00:00am.  The second field is a 3 to 4 digit integer that represents the hours and minutes of the transaction in a military time format.  I'm trying to create a view that will, among other things, show those 2 fields combined in one datetime field.  Is it possible?  I'm going to need to do some time interval calculations and it would be easier to deal with them if they were together.

Comment: Please provide examples

Comment: why not just FIX the table, combine the time into the datetime column once and for all.  Then, you won't need to do this ridiculous manipulation each time the view is run??  a single UPDATE command and a DROP COLUMN should fix the bad design.

Comment: I can't fix it.  It's a table generated by a third party system.  I have to use it the way it is.

Comment: @LMGroup - I feel your pain.

Comment: This is what the data looks like...  
  
Job     TranN   Status  Date                    Time    Employee
639535 10 10000 11/12/2013 12:00:00 AM 1442 838
639535 20 10335 11/12/2013 12:00:00 AM 1451 838
639535 30 9095 11/12/2013 12:00:00 AM 1451 838
639535 40 9090 11/12/2013 12:00:00 AM 1615 851
639535 50 10000 11/13/2013 12:00:00 AM 747 847
639535 60 9095 11/13/2013 12:00:00 AM 747 847
639535 70 10000 11/13/2013 12:00:00 AM 1053 847
639535 80 10498 11/13/2013 12:00:00 AM 1057 888
639535 90 10340 11/13/2013 12:00:00 AM 1325 888
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: How do I make that data look legible?  This is my first post on here.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries. You should be able to **edit** the question itself. You can paste the data into there, and [format it as fixed-width code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this `dateadd(minute,dateadd(hour,DateColumn,TimeColumn/100),TimeColumn%100)` might get you close.

Comment: Once I rearranged the pieces, it worked like a charm.  Thanks so much, @uncle brad!

Comment: @LMGroup - Oops, I guess I flip-flopped the div and mod.

Comment: @LMGroup - Will you "Accept" my answer?